# Косинусное сходство (косинусная мера) для строк

Tags: алгоритм

Допустим, есть два текстовых документа, векторами которых будут два массива, состоящие из их слов: `D1 = {word1, word2, word3}` и `D2 = {word1, word5, word8}`.

Как найти косинусное сходство двух этих векторов? Как вообще перемножить (или провести другие математические операции) со строками в рамках какого-то языка программирования?

И как быть если векторы будут разных размеров? (Например, в одном документе будет больше слов, чем в другом).

Comment: Косинусная мера для числовых векторов это их скалярное произведение, деленное на произведение их модуле: x*y/(|x|*|y|). Видимо, предполагается, что вы каким-то образом охарактеризуете тексты числовыми векторами. Вопрос, как вы это будете делать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В процессе написания обнаружилось, что тема крайне велика, чтобы ее можно было так просто кратко и понятно расписать в ответе. Я бы рекомендовал обратиться к классическим учебникам - из них вы узнаете гораздо больше. Например, [IR-Book](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/). Тем не менее:

---

Вы не можете проводить математические операции над строками. Можете с векторами. Процесс перехода к векторам называется векторизацией. Векторизация естественных языков языков тема относительно хорошо изученная - самый известный мне пример - это [word2vec](https://github.com/dav/word2vec) - можете вместо своих велосипедов сразу начать с него (или с какого-нибудь побратима [doc2vec](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/le14.pdf)). Одна с ним проблема - детальный разбор механизма разбора требует довольно высокой квалификации. Но никто не запрещает пользовать этот инструмент как черный ящик.

Теперь о велосипедах. Можно взять простую реализацию [TF-IDF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TF-IDF) - с помощью нее можно получить вектора и оперировать с векторами. Писать я буду на Python без использования специфических конструкций (предпочитаемый язык у вас не указан).

Порядок моих действий такой:

1. Из корпуса составить словарь слов, где ключом будет слово, а значением - индекс в векторе (каждое слово - отдельное измерение в получающихся векторах)
2. Для каждого документа в корпусе посчитать TF-IDF для всех слов из документа. После этого для каждого слова в документе можно будет сопоставить вектор размерностью `n`, где `n` - количество уникальных слов в корпусе (см. 1). В результате получаем [матрицу вхождения отдельных слов в документы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix). Такой подход называется [Bag of Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) (порядок слов в документе нарушается и представляется как мешок перемешанных слов) и TF-IDF вы можете заменить какой угодно мерой, что вам приглянется. Можно просто посчитать, сколько отдельное слово встречается в документе.
3. В дальнейшем вы можете сравнивать уже получившиеся вектора между собой или с новыми векторами.

Корпус такой:

```
str1 = "Я люблю тортики больше, чем яблоки"
str2 = "Я уважаю апельсины больше, чем торты"
str3 = "Яблочные сады раскинулись над дорогой"
str4 = "Ехал Грека через реку"
```

Как видно количество слов различно - так же проявляется еще одна проблема - одинаковые слова употребляются в разных формах/падежах (тортики-тортиков). Эта проблема решается разными путями - стеммингом (stemming), нормализацией - слова приводятся к единственному числу, именительному падежу (тортики - торт, тортиков - торт) - но это отдельная большая тема. Еще туда же - фильтрация знаков препинания - `больше,` и `больше` - разные слова (токены).

```py
from collections import Counter
import operator
import math


def tokenize(doc):
    words = [word.replace(',', '').lower() for word in doc.split()]
    return words


def build_terms(corpus):
    terms = {}
    current_index = 0
    for doc in corpus:
        for word in tokenize(doc):
            if word not in terms:
                terms[word] = current_index
                current_index += 1
    return terms


def tf(document, terms):
    words = tokenize(document)
    total_words = len(words)
    doc_counter = Counter(words)
    for word in doc_counter:
        # Можно и не делить, а оставить как есть, с частотой
        doc_counter[word] /= total_words
    tfs = [0 for _ in range(len(terms))]
    for term, index in terms.items():
        tfs[index] = doc_counter[term]
    return tfs


def _count_docs_with_word(word, docs):
    counter = 1
    for doc in docs:
        if word in doc:
            counter += 1
    return counter


# documents - это корпус
def idf(documents, terms):
    idfs = [0 for _ in range(len(terms))]
    total_docs = len(documents)
    for word, index in terms.items():
        docs_with_word = _count_docs_with_word(word, documents)
        # Основание логарифма не важно
        # Боюсь отрицательныз значений, только положительные
        idf = 1 + math.log10(total_docs / docs_with_word)
        idfs[index] = idf
    return idfs


def _merge_td_idf(tf, idf, terms):
    return [tf[i] * idf[i] for i in range(len(terms))]


def build_tfidf(corpus, document, terms):
    doc_tf = tf(document, terms)
    doc_idf = idf(corpus, terms)
    return _merge_td_idf(doc_tf, doc_idf, terms)


def cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2):
    # Целиком отсюда: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424228/cosine-similarity-between-2-number-lists
    def dot_product2(v1, v2):
        return sum(map(operator.mul, v1, v2))

    def vector_cos5(v1, v2):
        prod = dot_product2(v1, v2)
        len1 = math.sqrt(dot_product2(v1, v1))
        len2 = math.sqrt(dot_product2(v2, v2))
        return prod / (len1 * len2)

    return vector_cos5(vec1, vec2)


str1 = "Я люблю тортики больше, чем яблоки"
str2 = "Я уважаю апельсины больше, чем торты"
str3 = "Яблочные сады раскинулись над дорогой"
str4 = "Ехал Грека через реку"

# Проверочные документы
check_str1 = "Тортики делают из муки, апельсины и воды"
check_str2 = "Торты исчезли там, где появился я"
check_str3 = "Ехал тортик через реку"

# --------------------- Основной код --------------------

tf_idf_total = []
corpus = (str1, str2, str3, str4)
terms = build_terms(corpus)

for document in corpus:
    tf_idf_total.append(build_tfidf(corpus, document, terms))

print(terms.keys())
for doc_rating in tf_idf_total:
    print(doc_rating)


queries = (check_str1, check_str2, check_str3)
for query in queries:
    print("QUERY:", query)
    query_tfidf = build_tfidf(corpus, query, terms)
    for index, document in enumerate(tf_idf_total):
        print("Similarity with DOC", index, "=", cosine_similarity(query_tfidf, document))
```

Я хотел покороче, но не вышло. Результаты такие:

```
dict_keys(['я', 'люблю', 'тортики', 'больше', 'чем', 'яблоки', 'уважаю', 'апельсины', 'торты', 'яблочные', 'сады', 'раскинулись', 'над', 'дорогой', 'ехал', 'грека', 'через', 'реку'])
[0.21683833261066354, 0.21683833261066354, 0.21683833261066354, 0.18748978943471664, 0.18748978943471664, 0.21683833261066354, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.21683833261066354, 0.0, 0.0, 0.18748978943471664, 0.18748978943471664, 0.0, 0.21683833261066354, 0.21683833261066354, 0.21683833261066354, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3204119982655925, 0.26020599913279624, 0.26020599913279624, 0.26020599913279624, 0.26020599913279624, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4005149978319906, 0.4005149978319906, 0.3252574989159953, 0.3252574989159953]
QUERY: Тортики делают из муки, апельсины и воды
Similarity with DOC 0 = 0.3016416923422043
Similarity with DOC 1 = 0.3016416923422043
Similarity with DOC 2 = 0.0
Similarity with DOC 3 = 0.0
QUERY: Торты исчезли там, где появился я
Similarity with DOC 0 = 0.3016416923422042
Similarity with DOC 1 = 0.6032833846844085
Similarity with DOC 2 = 0.0
Similarity with DOC 3 = 0.0
QUERY: Ехал тортик через реку
Similarity with DOC 0 = 0.0
Similarity with DOC 1 = 0.0
Similarity with DOC 2 = 0.0
Similarity with DOC 3 = 0.8358857904935546
```

Comment: Небольшое замечание про "...для каждого слова в документе можно будет сопоставить вектор размерностью n, где n - количество уникальных слов в корпусе". 

Насколько я понял, тут речь идет о векторах для документов, а не для слов. Т.е. должно быть ".. каждому документу можно сопоставить вектор размерностью n, где n - количество уникальных слов в корпусе".